# Conversion of a specific character in a string to Upper Case

Tags: python, string, uppercase

How can I convert a specific letter in a string, i.e all the the `a`s in `'ahdhkhkahfkahafafkh'` to uppercase?

I can only seem to find ways to capitalize the first word or upper/lower case the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = 'ahdhkhkahfkahafafkh'
>>> "".join(i.upper() if i == 'a' else i for i in a)
'AhdhkhkAhfkAhAfAfkh'
```

Or

```
>>> a.replace('a',"A")
'AhdhkhkAhfkAhAfAfkh'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `str.translate` with `string.maketrans`:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('a', 'A')
>>> 'abcdefgahajkl'.translate(table)
'AbcdefgAhAjkl'
```

This really shines if you want to replace `'a'` and `'b'` with their uppercase versions... then you just change the translation table:

```
table = string.maketrans('ab', 'AB')
```

---

Or, you can use `str.replace` if you really are only doing a 1 for 1 swap:

```
>>> 'abcdefgahajkl'.replace('a', 'A')
'AbcdefgAhAjkl'
```

This method shines when you only have one replacement.  It replaces substrings rather than characters, so `'Bat'.replace('Ba', 'Cas')` -> `'Cast'`.

Comment: Why is this better than .replace()?

Comment: Thank you! I had the replace function up I just didn't use the 'a', 'A', part!

Comment: @Finlandia_C For future reference, that's something that should be included in your question.  Show what you've tried, what it's giving you, and what you want instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
'banana'.replace('a', "A")
```

From the docs:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace